macOS 15: Clicking Dock Icon Opens Two Windows
Prior to macOS 15, when the user closed all windows and then clicked the Dock icon, the app wouldn't reopen a window. To handle this, I added the applicationShouldHandleReopen method in the AppDelegate, which worked well in earlier macOS versions, allowing the app to reopen a window when the user clicked the Dock icon.
However, after upgrading to macOS 15, I've noticed an issue:

When I click the Dock icon, two windows open instead of one.

If I comment out the applicationShouldHandleReopen method, only one window opens, which is the expected behavior.


Here’s the relevant code snippet:
 func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
        guard let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first else { assertionFailure(); return false }
        if !flag {
            window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        }
        return true
    }

Tried Adding this to ignore this method for macOS15 but didn't work, it doesn't allow the window to launch to begin with.
@available(macOS, introduced: 10.0, obsoleted: 15.0)

I had the same issue. Checking if there's already a window fixed it:
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
  if !flag {
    sender.windows.first?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
  }

  return sender.windows.isEmpty ? true : false
}

